# How to receive weight from a Bluetooth Low Energy Weighing Machine in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I currently have a BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) Weighing Machine which gives the weight, BMI, temperature and few other values when a person stands on it. I would like to get these values in my desktop application. I tried checking the BluetoothLEAdvertisement method, but still I'm not getting any value. It would be great if anyone could share a snippet on how it works!!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Start the program
        var program = new Program();

        // Close on key press
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public Program()
    {
        // Create Bluetooth Listener
        var watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();

        watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;

        // Only activate the watcher when we're recieving values >= -80
        watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.InRangeThresholdInDBm = -80;

        // Stop watching if the value drops below -90 (user walked away)
        watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeThresholdInDBm = -90;

        // Register callback for when we see an advertisements
        watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;

        // Wait 5 seconds to make sure the device is really out of range
        watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.OutOfRangeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
        watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.SamplingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

        // Starting watching for advertisements
        watcher.Start();
    }

    private void OnAdvertisementReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // Tell the user we see an advertisement and print some properties
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Advertisement:"));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  BT_ADDR: {0}", eventArgs.BluetoothAddress));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  FR_NAME: {0}", eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  FR_NAME: {0}", eventArgs.Advertisement.DataSections.ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

This is the code that I currently have. Someone pleasee help meee!! :)

Comment: Have you looked into GATT client description at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client) ?

Comment: Yes. In fact I think the snippet I have provided, have few aspects of GATT. I couldn't find any method that gives me data from a bluetooth device. If you are aware, please do share! :)